# Make Nginx caching respect cache-control headers

Tags: performance, http, caching, nginx, reverse-proxy

Nginx can cache content, ie act as a reverse-proxy, but the purge time must be fixed in the Nginx config.

Is there a way to make Nginx purge automatically according to cache-control headers from upstream app servers?

Comment: nginx already does this. http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cache_valid parameters of caching may be set in the header fields “Expires” or “Cache-Control”.

Comment: Could be. I read it wasn't possible (can't find the source atm). Have you tried it? I wonder how it resolves between the cache limit defined in nginx config and the one in the header. e.g. would it just ignore the nginx config length or apply the minimum of both values.

Comment: “Parameters of caching can also be **set directly in the response header**. This has **higher priority** than setting of caching time using the directive.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching this issue, I found it's not well documented as most people seem concerned with CMSs where it's easy to say "cache articles for a day", but less so for dynamic app servers which may vary according to each request.

Several options are:

- [Nginx Plus](https://www.nginx.com/products/content-caching-nginx-plus/)
- [Ngx Cache Purge module](https://github.com/FRiCKLE/ngx_cache_purge), though it hasn't seen any updates in 2 years
- Define multiple caches with different expiry times and apply them differently by path, if that's possible.
- Forget caching on Nginx and put a server like Varnish in front of it.

Update: Looking further, I now think proxy_cache_valid doesn't even need to be present. It just sets a default expiry if there's no cache-control/expiry from upstream. Nginx will still consider content as stale if there's no proxy_cache_valid, but it won't immediately be purged. The reason it keeps stale content in the cache (determined with "inactive" param and optionally proxy_cache_valid) is that it can serve stale content using [proxy_cache_use_stale](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_use_stale) (useful if there's an error upstream).